Проблема с фоном в библиотеке tkinter
Пишу простенькую прогу и возникла проблема, когда добавляю какой-то виджет он добавляется вместе c бело-серой рамкой вокруг него. 
Это рамка не убирается borderwidth и highlightthickness.
Как ее убрать? Фон принципиально хочется оставить свой, а не менять под цвет этой рамки.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Определение серийника")
window.geometry('600x400')
window.resizable(False, False)

main_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="main.png")

logo_label = tk.Label(window, image=main_image)
logo_label.image = main_image

frame = Frame(window, padx=10, pady=10)
logo_label.place(x=-2,y=0)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

name = Label(
    frame,
    text="Нажмите кнопку снизу для поиска",
    font=("Arial", 17, "bold"),
)
name.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10,40))
window.mainloop()



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с формулировки заголовка

Прозрачный фон для меток не поддерживается в Tkinter.
Как вариант можно использовать Canvas.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Определение серийника")
window.geometry('660x620')
window.resizable(False, False)

frame = Frame(window, padx=0, pady=0)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, height=620, width=660)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 10))

bg_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="layer1bg.png")
bg_label = canvas.create_image((0, 0), 
    image=bg_img, anchor=tk.N+tk.W)
your_text = canvas.create_text((330, 520), 
    text="Нажмите кнопку снизу для поиска", 
    font="Arial 20 bold", 
    fill="#800000")
    
btn = Button(frame, text="Поиск",
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(570, 0))

window.mainloop()


